# win32: child window not found in child's parent's children

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I have an Internet explorer page which generated a pop-up. I can get the parent from the pop-up window's handle:

```
>>> child.handle
15208472
>>> win32gui.GetParent(child.handle)
33230502
```

But I can't find the child's handle by using `EnumChildWindows`:

```
>>> win32gui.EnumChildWindows(win32gui.GetParent(child.handle), lambda hwnd,p: child_handles.append(hwnd), None)
>>> len(child_handles)
39
>>> child.handle in child_handles
False
```

I've done this recursively as well (getting the children of all the children) and still no child handle to be found. Why might this be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popup window isn't a child window, so can't be enumerated with `EnumChildWindows`.

When you called `win32gui.GetParent` you actually got the "owner" window of the popup, but "owner" and "parent" are two different things. See the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#parent_owner_handle) for more infromation.

Comment: ah gotcha. how do I get all of a window's owned windows, then? is the only way to enum all windows and return those whose parent is the specific one and that aren't in the parent's child windows? (seems like a long-about way to do it)

Comment: You can do that using the EnumWindows function and comparing each window's owner against the target window. If the windows are in the same thread then using EnumThreadWindows in the same manner may be more efficient.

Comment: how do I get a window's owner?

Comment: ah here it is: `owner_handle = win32gui.GetWindow(self.handle, win32con.GW_OWNER)`

Comment: GetParent (as you were doing) also returns the owner for a popup window, fwiw.

Comment: Yes, but then I don't know whether it is a child window or an owned window. I wanted to be able to differentiate between the two

Comment: EnumWindows only returns top-level (popup) windows so there's no risk it's a child. Anyway, whatever method you come up with that works is probably fine :)